# Why TelephonyManager.getDeviceId() returns device ID that made with only zeros?

Tags: android, uuid

I wanted to get my android device's UUID, so I was try to get UUID with TelephonyManager.getDeviceId() method. But it returns device ID that made with only 0s (like 000000000000).

Here is my code. Many lines of code were used to get user permission READ_PHONE_STATE.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        int permissionResult = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        if(permissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Need Permission")
                        .setMessage("This needs to READ_PHONE_STATE Permission. Continue?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 1000);
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();
            }
            else{
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 1000);
            }
        }
        else{
            tv.setText(GetDeviceUUID(getBaseContext()));
        }
    }
    tv.setText(GetDeviceUUID(getBaseContext()));
}

public static String GetDeviceUUID(Context mContext){
    */
    TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    final String ID = mgr.getDeviceId();
    return ID;
}

@Override
public Context getBaseContext() {
    return super.getBaseContext();
}
```

}

Comment: Are you running on emulator?

Comment: getDeviceId() Returns the unique device ID, for example, the IMEI for GSM and the MEID or ESN for CDMA phones. Return null if device ID is not available.

This is behavior of getDeviceID() method, But I want know are testing application on emulator?

Comment: Thanks for help. Yes I was test on emulator :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes that returns 0 for emulators as emulator does not have an IMEI number. 
Use this to generate the deviceId:

```
final String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;
                tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
                tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
                androidId = "" + android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getAppContext().getContentResolver(),
                        android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

                UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(), ((long) tmDevice.hashCode() << 32) | tmSerial.hashCode());
```

This will give you a unique deviceId.